# Remove youtube context menu from iframe android webview

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, webchromeclient

When load a url in webview which contains iframe and embedded youtube video in it youtube doesn't show context menu. But when i load iframe with embeded youtube using HTML in webview it shows context menu on scroll.

[image: youtube video with context menu]

i have tried disabling long click on webview it still shows context menu. I don't want to use youtube api cause in webview there will be other elements as well.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you solved this problem? [My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75600600/android-webview-keeps-opening-context-menu)

Comment: No. but i have pinpoint the problem. when i use nested scroll view there is context menu. but when remove it i dont get any context menu.